# How to create a second column of evenly spaced equations/text

Tags: spacing

I am making a problem set for a calculus class using LaTex, and  I am running into an issue.

My code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\modparskip
\newlength\modbaselineskip
 \def\baselinestretch{1} % this parameter will be redefined at start of 'spacing' environment
 \setlength\modparskip{\parskip/\real{\baselinestretch}}%
 \setlength\modbaselineskip{\baselineskip/\real{\baselinestretch}}%
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{spacing}[1]{\par%
  \def\baselinestretch{#1}%
  \ifx\@currsize\normalsize\@normalsize\else\@currsize\fi%
}%
{\par%
  \vskip \modparskip%      % originally: \vskip \parskip
  \vskip \modbaselineskip% % originally: \vskip \baselineskip
}
\makeatother


\title{Power Rule Mini Quiz}
\author{Zachary Taylor Warde }
\date{June 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{spacing}{3.0}

\textbf{For Questions 1-10, use the power rule to find the derivative of each function. Show all work.}

\large

\textbf{1.} $f(x) = 3x^{3}$
\end{spacing}
\large
\begin{spacing}{6.5}\textbf{2.} \( f(x) = 2x^{4} + x + 5 \) \hspace{2.55in}\textbf{6.} \( f(x) = \displaystyle e^{5\ln{x}} - e^{-3\ln{x}} \)

\textbf{3.} \( f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{x^2 + 5x + 4}{x+4} \) \hspace{2.55in}\textbf{7.}

\textbf{4.} \( f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{x^4} + 3x + 2 \)

\textbf{5.} \( f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{x^{13}}\)


\end{spacing}


\end{document}
```

I want the horizontal space between the second column of problems to be equal, but putting a fixed difference does not achieve this because the problems are different lengths. How can I make it so the next 5 exercises appear in a column as the first 5 do? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please make separate questions for separate enquiries. Also, your code isn't compilable, it's missing (at least) a documentclass command.

Comment: Why don't you use the `tasks` package and its eponymous environment? It is easily customisable.

Comment: You could `\smash` the math so that they do not affect your spacing.  I would use `\parbox[c][5\baselineskip][c]{\columnwidth}{...}` (or minipage) and multicols.